# How to get the realtime data into sql server database from a mdb file which update frequently?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I got access to mdb file from a third party user. This mdb file is updated frequently (2-3 time in a minute). I want to extract the realtime data from this mdb file into the SQL Server database.

What I did:
I have linked that mdb file to the SQL server database but the update in mdb is not reflected in SQL DB.

Can you guys suggest simple way to extract mdb file data to sql db in realtime.

Comment: You need replication. Google for `access replication options`

Comment: show us the code you wrote for the update

Comment: I haven't used any code for linking and update. First I imported the mdb file into Sql server db and then I just connected that sql server by using the ODBC Database option in the Extenal Data tab in MS Access.